# How to continuously remove / delete an element

Tags: javascript

This is a chrome extension.

Hi, I'm trying to remove / delete a specific users messages in a chat room. It successfully removes all messages from the user but if the user post another message it wont get removed / deleted. To solve that I tried putting my code inside a timeout function that runs every 100 millisecond but that didn't work.

This is a chrome extension

Code:

```
// Remove a specific users message(s)
function removeMessages() {
    // Run every 100 millisecond
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Get all username fields inside iframe
        var users = $('#content-frame').contents().find('.chat-item__username');
        // Delete this users message(s)
        var rudeUser = '@username';
        // Find messages posted by rudeUser
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
            if(users.eq(i).text() == rudeUser){
                //Remove message
                users.eq(i).closest('.read').remove();
            }
        }
        // Loop / run again
        removeMessages();
    }, 100);
}

removeMessages();
```

Comment: What does `users.eq(i)` do? Maybe you meant to do `users[i]` or `users.get(i)`. I'm now sure what API you're using `$` jQuery? Maybe you could provide some HTML, with out that how can we know if your selectors are correct?

Comment: You could use setInterval instead using setTimeout and recalling the method at the end

Comment: You might be able to overwrite the function that updates the chat to filter out all new messages before it displays them

Comment: All the selectors are correct. The script successfully removes all messages from a user but if the user post another question, that message wont get removed.

Comment: @NickSlash Good idea! Thanks!